# Boyer-Moore jump table

Tags: strings, substrings, string-matching

I have a pattern $P$ of length $m$, i.e. $P = p_0, p_1, \ldots, p_{m-1}$
which I want to build a simple jump table for (not considering special optimizing cases for now).

I only want to build a jump table based on matching suffixes of $P$ (the `bad character rule` is not relevant here).

The problem is to build a table such like this one:

[image]

where `suffix[i]` is the longest suffix of $P[1 \ldots i]$ that is also a suffix of $P$ as a whole
and `beta(i)` is a heuristic which tells how much you may shift the pattern against an arbitrary text $T$ on mismatch.

I am able to build the `suffix`-table but I have no idea how to use these values to build the `beta` array/function from that. The definition the professor gave me for this is also really sloppy and a jumbled mess of indices which does not give me any intuition.

Just by looking at it you could spot that for example at $i = 6$ you have `beta(i) = 2`. If we look at the pattern we have the suffix $P[6 \ldots 8]$ and the closest occurrence of this suffix is at position $i = 4$. If we shift by $2$ we have these characters aligned for free. But it could also be the suffix $P[7\ldots8]$ ($i+1$) and its reoccurrence at $i = 5$ which would result in the same shift.

We notice: for $i=6$ we want to find the longest suffix starting at $i$ (or $i+1, i+2, \ldots$?) which is also a suffix of some prefix of $P$. (which, essentially, is a substring but I guess defining it as a suffix of a prefix makes more sense since I need to use the `suffix`-table)

So

1. Do we always want to find occurrences of suffixes of $P$ starting at $i$ or any suffix from $i$ onwards up to $m-1$?
2. If there are both, which one to choose? The longest?
3. How did these $7$s get calculated?

Comment: Welcome to COMPUTER **SCIENCE** @SE. Who originated the example above, where does it come from? Please include the *pattern*.

Comment: @greybeard the pattern is the top row, $P[i]$. The alphabet is just $\{0,1\}$